# Can multiple rails application use one redis for resque jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

Is there anyway to use one redis (for background jobs ) for multiple rails application ?

EDIT:

If I use same redis for all the applications then a redis have many jobs queued from different application, which raise the issue that Resque of an app may process the wrong job.

Comment: Yes, you will need to point your all applications to a single particular redis server..

Comment: Yeah, but there several jobs queued in redis from different apps and they have there own Resque to process the jobs. So how redis can distinguish which job is for which application.

And the issue is, Resque of an app may process the wrong job.

Comment: Use Redis, and use the same database number but separate queue names for each app.. In your apps, you will need to specify queue name for each app

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation you can setup Resque to use a namespace to connect to redis like this:

```
Resque.configure do |config|
  # Set the redis connection. Takes any of:
  #   String - a redis url string (e.g., 'redis://host:port')
  #   String - 'hostname:port[:db][/namespace]'
  #   Redis - a redis connection that will be namespaced :resque
  #   Redis::Namespace - a namespaced redis connection that will be used as-is
  #   Redis::Distributed - a distributed redis connection that will be used as-is
  #   Hash - a redis connection hash (e.g. {:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :db => 0})
  config.redis = 'localhost:6379:alpha/high'
end
```